# com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService' is not assignable to 'android.app.Service'

Tags: android, parse-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

To start off, I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049844/myfirebasemessagingserviceservice-is-not-assignable-to-android-app-service) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436100/myfirebasemessaging-service-is-not-assignable-to-android-app-service) post, asking similar questions, but both of them don't seem to solve the problem I am having.

**What am I trying to do?**

I am upgrading an application from Google Cloud Messaging to Firebase Cloud Messaging using a Parse server. There are a couple of tutorials on this (I'm using [this one](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#android-apps)), all specifying that you need to add the following lines in your manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**What is going wrong?**

However, if I do so I get the error *com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService' is not assignable to 'android.app.Service*. I cannot seem to find any resource on how to solve this, or whether it is an issue at all for receiving any messages.

My Project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

And my Module gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-fcm-android:1.17.3' // Firebase cloud messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.mtotschnig:stickylistheaders:2.7.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

Any ideas what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Try using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58431452/2637449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Md. Asaduzzaman's answer was helpful, thanks for that.

Just to add to it, make sure to override the onNewToken() method in your custom FirebaseMessagingService, like in [this](https://medium.com/android-school/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated-50651f17a148) tutorial. (I just found the tutorial and thought it would be nice to share it if others are stuck with the same problem).

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);
}
```

We need to override it because:

"Class FirebaseInstanceIdService:
This class was deprecated.
In favour of overriding onNewToken in FirebaseMessagingService.

Once that has been implemented, this service can be safely removed."

Comment: Glad to hear that. Hit the up button there to support it